# Index Notation: Vector Calculus

Tags: vectors

I'm stuck on a few questions relating to Index Notation. I'm trying to grasp it however help on these questions would further my understanding of the concepts.

1)How do I show that

$$\nabla(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b})=\mathbf{a} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{b})+\mathbf{b} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{a})+ \mathbf{a} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{b})+\mathbf{b} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{a})$$ using index notation? Where $\nabla=\partial_{i}\space$, $\times$ represents the cross product and $\cdot$ represents the scalar product.

2) How do I show that

$$\nabla \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{a}=0$$

using index notation?

3) How do I show that

$$∇ × (\mathbf{a} × \mathbf{b}) = \mathbf{a}(∇ · \mathbf{b}) − \mathbf{b}(∇ · \mathbf{a}) + (\mathbf{b} · ∇)\mathbf{a} − (\mathbf{a} · ∇)\mathbf{b}$$ using index notation?

Thank you for any help or guidance you can offer!

Comment: A helpful identity to keep in mind is $\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{ilm}=\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}$. Also remember product rule $\partial(AB) = \partial(A)B+A\partial(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

I will not do all the calculation for you, but I can give you two hints:

(using trivial metrix $\delta_{ij}$ and thus only lower indices)

$$\vec a \cdot \vec b = \sum_i a_ib_i$$
$$\vec a \times \vec b = \sum_i a_kb_\ell \varepsilon_{k\ell i} $$
With the Levi-Cevita Symbol $\varepsilon_{k\ell i}$

With these notations you can show the three assumptions.

Comment: You cross product expansion is incorrect.  It should be $$\vec a \times \vec b = \sum_k\sum_l\sum_i a_kb_l\epsilon_{kli}\hat e_i$$ or $$[\vec a\times \vec b]_i= \sum_k\sum_l a_kb_l\epsilon_{kli}$$